# Capture the enter key cross-browser, my solution isn't working

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, enter

I have what I thought was a cross-browser solution to capturing the enter key in a chat script I'm making, here it is:

```
    nn=(document.layers)?true:false;
ie=(document.all)?true:false;
function keyDown(e) {
    var evt=(e)?e:(window.event)?window.event:null;
    if(evt){
        var key=(evt.charCode)?evt.charCode: ((evt.keyCode)?evt.keyCode:((evt.which)?evt.which:0));
        if(key=="13") document.getElementById('chatEnter').submit();
        }
    }
document.onkeydown=keyDown;
if(nn) document.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
```

I got this from someone else so perhaps it's outdated?  Anyway, the form id attribute is chatEnter as you can see.  I've also tried using document.forms[0].submit and that didn't work either.  It works just fine in FF but no luck in IE8 64 bit (those are the only two I've tested on thus far.)  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using >

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == "13") { 
        //enter pressed 
    }       
});
```

ofcourse you would require jQuery for it. There can't be a better cross-browser solution than to use a tested and widely used cross browser framework.

Comment: Adding jQuery just for this one solution seems like quite a bit of overhead.  If I don't get any more answers, though, that might just have to be the route to take.  I would think, though, that if jQuery can do it in a framework that there is a way for me to do it without the framework.  They had to code it some how.

Comment: @linus: yea, it does seem like an overkill for a situation. I don't exactly know the amount of Javascript you are writing for your application but considering it's a chat system, I suspect it's a lot. jQuery was born out to deal with cross-browser issue and you can expect to have more issues in future unless you use a similar framework (and it's only 29kb).

Comment: It's pretty light javascript, just a few lines for AJAX and then PHP does all the heavy lifting.  Hence my issue with adding jQuery.

Comment: I decided to say screw it and just include the minimum jquery to get it done.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

You're correct, the example you got is massively outdated and contains code to deal with Netscape 4, which has been irrelevant for about a decade.

Don't use jQuery just for this. It's not hard, if it's just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you want to capture:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("chatEnter").submit();
    }
};
```